# Why does my code change ALL the p tags in my page?

Tags: javascript, text, rotator

This code

```js
var current = 0,
    slides = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

p + p { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

is what I'm looking for to change the text on my page. However, when I add the p tags

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

all the paragraphs on the page will start to change. How can I specifically target just these three paragraphs tags?

Comment: Right, yes you're targeting ALL the p tags `document.getElementsByTagName("p");` add a class

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not only on an external site. @Liam has copied your code from jsFiddle to this site, thereby changing the terms under which your code is licensed. You should be doing this yourself, as the holder of the copyright.

Comment: I don't think he's going to be getting involved with a patent battle with this...

Comment: Thank you, I'll study the code more carefully to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Ps in a container or give them a class and use querySelectorAll

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nb7pkqy5/

```
slides = document.querySelectorAll("#container p");
```

```js
var current = 0,
  slides = document.querySelectorAll("#container p");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

```css
#container p {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

#container p+p {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Other paragraph</p>

<div id="container">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```